# What means E letter in phpunit tests?

Tags: php, unit-testing, testing, phpunit

What means letters E and F in PHPUnit tests?

```
..............F................................................  63 / 348 ( 18%)
.............................................................F. 126 / 348 ( 36%)
............................................................... 189 / 348 ( 54%)
.........E..................................................... 252 / 348 ( 72%)
...................................................F........... 315 / 348 ( 90%)
.................................                               348 / 348 (100%)
```

Comment: Um, ***E***rror......

Answer (score 3):

From the doc (https://phpunit.readthedocs.io/en/9.2/textui.html):

> `F` Printed when an assertion fails while running the test method.
>
> `E` Printed when an error occurs while running the test method.

The important distinction is that `F` means the code you are testing failed the test. Whereas `E` means something prevented the test from completing, such as a problem with the test code itself, or syntax error, etc.